# Hiding field of custom-multi-field using javascript in listener

Tags: javascript, aem

I have customized form of multi-field in a component having two variations.
In one variation of my component I want to hide a field (title) which is inside custom-multi-field . I am using the following JavaScript code in listener.
This code is not working. Where am I wrong?

```
function() {
    var dialog = this.findParentByType('dialog');
    var contenttype = dialog.getField("./type").getValue();
    var teaserlinks = dialog.getField("./teaserlinks");
    var title = dialog.getField("./teaserlinks").getField("./title");
    alert(title);
    if(contenttype == 'variation-1'){
        teaserlinks.show();
        title.hide();
    }
    else if(contenttype == 'variation-2'){
        teaserlinks.show();    
    }
}
```

Comment: what value you are getting in alert?

Comment: it was just for checking the value of title in webpage. its coming out to be undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the hidden property of node. Initially set the hidden property to true and in javascript file change the hidden property to false (or as per your requirement).

Comment: can you please elaborate the use of hidden field? How to access it?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Component"
    jcr:title="Footer"
    hidden="{Boolean}true"/>                                                                   This is the sample componet which is hidden initially.Assume this is in your customised multi-field , traverse upto this component in the javascript code and change the hidden value to false.

Answer (score 1):

Few imp points first before answer:

1. you have to write listener in your widget file only.
2. below is the sample code where in I have 2 fields. 1st field is **mytext** field and another field is **myselection**. On changing the value in myselection field I am toggling visibility of my text field.

Below is snippet:

```
this.mytext = new CQ.form.textField({...})

this.myselection = new CQ.form.Selection({
    fieldLabel:"my selection",
    type:"select",
    width : "325",
    allowBlank:false,
    defaultType:"String[]",
    fieldDescription : "Select value from dropdown",
    options: "/a/b/c.json",
    listeners : {
        selectionchanged : function(){
            var mytext = this.findParentByType('mywidget').mytext;

            mytext.hide();
        }
    }
});
```

I hope this will be helpful.

Comment: I am looking for hiding the sub-field of custom-multi-field. Can you please share any example of that?

Comment: @NainyJain This example which I gave is about hiding a text field inside (or a sub-field) multifield. I suggest you to try implementing listener in your widget.js file as described above, you will get the solution. Above here I have provided working code, which I am using in my application.

Answer (score 0):

I have no knowledge about aem and Adobe CQ5 but I can give you some hints how to debug your script.

First of all don't use `alert` for debugging!  (BTW what does `alert(title);` show?)

I would recommend to open the browser console (e.g. Press `<F12>` on Firefox and switch to the tab "Console").

Herein the browser displays all exceptions and error messages. Additionally you can output some text with console.log("...");` from your script.

Here is my edit of your program. Perhaps the output can help you.

```
function()
{
  var dialog = this.findParentByType('dialog');
  var contenttype = dialog.getField("./type").getValue();

  var teaserlinks = dialog.getField("./teaserlinks");
  var title = dialog.getField("./teaserlinks").getField("./title");
  console.dir(title);
  console.log(contenttype);

  teaserlinks.show();
  if(contenttype == 'variation-1')
  {
    title.hide();
  }
  else if(contenttype == 'variation-2')
  { 
    title.show();
  } 
}
```

And, `console.dir(<object>);` shows you the object structure to one level deep.

Comment: alert(title) is showing undefined. That is my approach of using var title = dialog.getField("./teaserlinks").getField("./title"); is not correct i guess.